# odata works from address bar, fails from javascript

Tags: javascript, odata, response, odata-v4, olingo

Javascript app to consume oData V4 using olingo oData library.
From address bar in browser I type: http://services.odata.org/v4/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Customers/
Returns json just fine...
**Here are the Headers from Fiddler..**
**Request Header**

```
 GET /v4/Northwind/Northwind.svc/ HTTP/1.1
    Host: services.odata.org
    Connection: keep-alive
    Accept:     text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.132 Safari/537.36
    DNT: 1
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
    Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
    Cookie: _ga=GA1.2.708581054.1436795740;   ARRAffinity=870cb949c1993c275a53bfec11e8eb1d159f40c7499f7f9453d895f29b9057a1
```

**Reply Header**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 3097
Content-Type: application/xml;charset=utf-8
Expires: Wed, 22 Jul 2015 19:43:25 GMT
Vary: *
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
OData-Version: 4.0;
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Accept, Origin, Content-Type, MaxDataServiceVersion
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: DataServiceVersion
Date: Wed, 22 Jul 2015 19:42:24 GMT
```

**The problem is from the javascript I make a call using using the exact same same uri olingo oDatajs and it fails in Preflight with not implemented **

```
OPTIONS /V4/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Customers HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Origin: http://localhost:3238
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept, odata-maxversion
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Host: services.odata.org
Content-Length: 0
DNT: 1
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
```

**Response Header**

```
HTTP/1.1 501 Not Implemented
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 49
Content-Type: application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=true;IEEE754Compatible=false;charset=utf-8
Expires: Wed, 22 Jul 2015 19:35:15 GMT
Vary: *
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
OData-Version: 4.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Accept, Origin, Content-Type, MaxDataServiceVersion
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: DataServiceVersion
Set-Cookie: ARRAffinity=870cb949c1993c275a53bfec11e8eb1d159f40c7499f7f9453d895f29b9057a1;Path=/;Domain=services.odata.org
Date: Wed, 22 Jul 2015 19:34:14 GMT
```

I have to assume it is something in the Request Header since the failure is before the return response hits the browser.
I have an oData V4 endpoint on a local server and have been able to get past the CORS only to have it return a 404 even though I can process the same URI from the address bar.

Address Bar Headers for that one
**Request**

```
GET /odata/Addresses?$top=10 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:43076
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.132 Safari/537.36
DNT: 1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

**Response**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
DataServiceVersion: 3.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B? TjpcQXNwUHJvamVjdHNcRmxleENvcmVcRmxleENvcmVcb2RhdGFcQWRkcmVzc2Vz?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 22 Jul 2015 18:44:05 GMT
Content-Length: 23418
```

And the Failing Headers from the javascript on this one...
**Request**

```
GET /odata/Addresses?$top=10 HTTP/1.1
OData-MaxVersion: 4.0
Accept: application/json;q=0.9, */*;q=0.1
Referer: http://localhost:3238/
Accept-Language: en-US
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Host: localhost:43076
DNT: 1
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

**Response**

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?    TjpcQXNwUHJvamVjdHNcRmxleENvcmVcRmxleENvcmVcb2RhdGFcQWRkcmVzc2Vz?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 22 Jul 2015 18:44:35 GMT
Content-Length: 3186
```

As you can see the Host and the GET are IDENTICAL in both cases so I don't understand why I am getting the 404 on the javascript requests. Does anyone who understands these headers better than I do see anything?

**UPDATE** 
I have determined the problem with the second half of my problem (hitting my local server) to be "OData-MaxVersion: 4.0" in the request header. The ASP.Net odata local server was running oData Version 3. Once I reworked the back end to oData v4 it returned the payload just fine. I determined the problem by removing the request header values one by one in fiddler until it worked.

Less of an issue for me but still unresolved is the Northwind oData returning 501 on the preflight here is the javascript function calling a oDatajs-4.0.0 function

```
var headers = { "Content-Type": "application/json", Accept: "application/json,text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8" };
                var request = {
                    requestUri: "http://services.odata.org/V4/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Customers",
                    method: "GET",
                    headers: headers,
                    data: null
                };


                odatajs.oData.request(request, function (data, response) {
                    if ((response.statusCode == '200') &&
                        (response.body.indexOf('}', response.body.length - 1) == response.body.length - 1) &&
                        response.headers['Content-Type'] == "application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=true;IEEE754Compatible=false;charset=utf-8") {
                        document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML += ("<div>odatajs V4 testing pass!</div>");
                    } else {
                        document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML += ("<div>odatajs V4 testing failed.</div>");
                    }
                }, function (err) {
                    document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML += ("<div>odatajs V4 testing failed.</div>");
                });
```

Comment: You should post your javascript code

Comment: Since the problem appears to be with the dissimilarities between the working and failing request response headers i thought the code would just convolute the issue.

Comment: I'll second that, can we see the javascript please? Specifically for the Northwind one so that we can try and reproduce it.

Comment: @JeffC and why do you think the requests are different? (The javascript)

Comment: OK, I found the answer, At least to the second half. The problem was the "OData-MaxVersion: 4.0" in the Request Header in the failing request. That particular ASP.Net server was running oData version 3. I updated the oData server to version 4 and it returned the payload, no problem.

Comment: @JeffC: Hi Jeff if the solution above solved your problem than you can post the same as answer and accept it :)